# How to set up JW Player (video Player) in asp .net page?

Tags: asp.net, jwplayer

I want to embed a JW Player (video player) in my asp .net page so that a user can play video files he/she uploads. How can I set up (integrate) a JW player?

Comment: The most basic set up is - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28833/quick-start-guide

Answer (score -1):

To embed the JW player into.Net application follows the below steps:

1. Import JW player Js library

2. Add JW player key

```html
<script>jwplayer.key = "jw  player key";</script>
```

3. Add the div for example

```html
<div>
    <iframe id="iJwplayer" src="" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"
            scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not fully answer the question, and in fact will produce no result.

Comment: The above code snippets are working code, where src is the URL from the CDN, for our case we are using JW dashboard.